# How to start and stop spawners at specific times in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I am trying to make an endless 2D game. I want to use 3-4 spawners for my game. My problem is that I can't set a specific time for my spawners.

After game started
First spawner will start spawning after 5 seconds and stops after 15 seconds, and it never turns on again.

Second spawner will start spawning after 15 seconds and stop after 25 seconds, and it never turns on again.

Third spawner will start spawning after 25 seconds and stop after 40 seconds, and it never turns on again.

I would like to use the same spawner script for all of them. I think I need some public values.

Here is my spawner code :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;    

public class RandomSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    bool isSpawning = false;
    public float minTime = 5.0f;
    public float maxTime = 15.0f;
    public Transform[] spawnPoints;
    public GameObject[] enemies;  

    IEnumerator SpawnObject(int index, float seconds)
    {
        Debug.Log("Waiting for " + seconds + " seconds");
        int spawnPointIndex = Random.Range(0, spawnPoints.Length);

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(seconds);
        Instantiate(enemies[index], spawnPoints[spawnPointIndex].position, transform.rotation);

        isSpawning = false;            
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (!isSpawning)
        {
            isSpawning = true; 
            int konumIndex = Random.Range(0, enemies.Length);
            StartCoroutine(SpawnObject(konumIndex, Random.Range(minTime, maxTime)));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use In-Built **InvokeRepeating** Method,You need to edit according to your Game.
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.InvokeRepeating.html

Answer (score 0):

One option I have used for this kind of thing is to test against Time.realtimeSinceStartup which gives you a the number of seconds since the game started:

```
if (Time.realtimeSinceStartup >= minTime && Time.realtimeSinceStartup <= maxTime) {
    //spawn stuff
}
```

That might be enough, but one extra thing to mention is if the start of your game is not exactly the correct reference point (for example your scene with the spawner created might start long after the game starts if you have a main menu first), then you might need to store a reference time for when the spawner is...uh...spawned. eg:

```
public class RandomSpawner : MonoBehaviour {
    float objectStartTime;
    void Start() {
        objectStartTime = Time.realtimeSinceStartup;
    }

    void Update() {
        var timeSinceObjectStart = Time.realtimeSinceStartup - objectStartTime;
        if (timeSinceObjectStart > minTime && timeSinceObjectStart < maxTime) {
        //spawn stuff
         }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!